# Append an entry of dataframe to a list, if the entry of another column is nan in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, list-comprehension

first question here so it might be a little bit messy.

So I have a data frame like this:

```
           A          B
1:        'a'       'aa'
2:        'b'       NaN
3:        'c'       NaN
4:        'd'       'dd'
```

And I have a list already created:

```
lst=[]
```

I want to append the value in `column A` to this `list` if the value of `Column B` is `NaN`, aka to get `['b','c']` in this case.

Loops definitely work but is there an elegant way (by using lambdas, for example) to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering and [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) for remove `'`:

```
lst = df.loc[df['B'].isnull(), 'A'].tolist()
print (lst)
["'b'", "'c'"]
```

---

```
lst = df.loc[df['B'].isnull(), 'A'].str.strip("'").tolist()
print (lst)
['b', 'c']
```

Detail:

```
print (df['B'].isnull())
1:    False
2:     True
3:     True
4:    False
Name: B, dtype: bool

print (df.loc[df['B'].isnull(), 'A'])
2:    'b'
3:    'c'
Name: A, dtype: object

print (df.loc[df['B'].isnull(), 'A'].str.strip("'"))
2:    b
3:    c
Name: A, dtype: object
```